# Web browser closes application

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to create a web browser using C# visual studio 2017.
I am experiencing something very strange.

All i did was drag the component into my form and changed the url to http://www.google.com

When i run the application it closes after a few seconds ignoring any breakpoints and form closing events.

Simply just stops as if somebody clicked stop.

Why is this happening?

EDIT:

Alot are requesting the code (without reading the post im guessing) but this is all i have up to know.. I havent touched any code yet:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

The exe file is even disappearing from the debug folder of the project!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Please include the code.

Comment: I can't, actually i don't have nothing to post as i said in the main post its a new winform application all i did was drag the webbrowser and directed the url to google from the properties

Comment: This is a common issue when you have antivirus installed that treats any unsigned executable trying to access the web as malware and remove it. Please stop the antivirus for a bit and try!

Comment: I do not have any antivirus application :/